# Best practice to use data objects on a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find the best practice to read a set of workers values from a csv file, these are my values:

```
worker_name department hiring_manager
 Albert Eine  Dept 11     Rob Tomas
 Eddie Stein  Dept 10     Seth Lowe
 Jim Wayne    Dept 12     Noel Gilligan
```

These values are going to be used in a function that I have to create these workers on the application, so what I'm trying is to use data structures and OOP to pass a list of data objects containing the set of data for each worker, the function should accept a single parameter called WorkerData that has what it needs from each row.

I tried to implement this solution:

```
import numpy
import pandas as pd
class AssignmentParameters:
    def __init__(self):
        self.df = pd.read_csv("client_assignments_first_gen.csv")
    def worker_data(self):
        row_list = []
        for rows in self.df.itertuples():
            my_list = [rows.worker_name, rows.department, rows.hiring_manager_label]
            row_list.append(my_list)
        return row_list
data = AssignmentParameters()
worker_data = data.worker_data()
print(worker_data[0])
print(worker_data[1])
print(worker_data[3])
```

And I was planning to use a loop so I would be able to get the values from these 3 workers but for what I have read this in not the ideal way and not the most sustainable code, that's why I'm finding a solution involving data structures, any recommendation of using stacks or queues to make data objects and pass them to the function that creates workers? any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, could you show what your desired output would look like?

Comment: I edited my question to give more details, the desired output would be passing every data object(these objects contain the values from each worker, worker name, department, hiring manager) to the function , something like `CreateWorker(DataObjectFromWorkers)`

Answer (score 0):

```
class AssignmentParameters:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.df = pd.read_csv(file)

    def create_worker_data(self):
        self.row_list = [{
            'name': rows.worker_name,
            'department': rows.department,
            'hiring_manager': rows.hiring_manager_label
            } for rows in self.df.itertuples()]

data = AssignmentParameters("client_assignments_first_gen.csv")
data.create_worker_data()

for worker in data.row_list:
    print(worker)
    print(worker['name'])
```

This will give you a list of dicts stored in the class, at least more accessible than a list of lists. But I'm sorry if I misunderstood your request